# Why does SQL job choke on stored package?

Tags: sql-server, spatial-database

I've written a stored package to pull a text file into a table in the geodatabase.  It works perfectly.  However, when it is a step in a SQL job, the job fails at that step.  I'm looking for ideas on how to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: Could you please provide more detail on the software you are using?  (Microsoft SQL Server 2008?  ArcGIS Server version? What kind of package?)

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2005, ArcGIS Server 9.3.1, Integration Services stored package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I had an issue similar to this in the past, it was a permissions issue. When I set up the job, I had to tell SQL Agent to run the step with the package as a user with the correct permission level.  May be a place to start looking.

Comment: Assuming that this is Microsoft SQL Server, that's the direction I'd look too.  That or, if the DTS/SSIS job is being tested on the desktop and run on the server, driver differences or path issues.

Comment: I'm testing and running on the server.  I have administrative privileges.  Can you be more specific about the permissions that need to be considered?

Comment: Sure. When your run the Integration Package in Visual Studio you are running it as yourself, with all of your privileges. When you set up a SQL job, the steps in the job are run by a specific user.  By default the user is the SQL Agent Service Account.  So when you run the job, it's trying to run your package step with the SQL Agent account.  The SQL Agent account does not by default have permissions to directories.  So the job fails when it tries to read your text file without having permission to.

Comment: cont. My workaround was to go under the Properties for the job step that runs my integration package, and assign it to be run as an administrator account.  You can use yourself, or an account set up just for running jobs.  I found that it has to be a network admin account, not a local account.  That is just my experience and what worked for me.